# Custom post structure in Wordpress breaks page name query functionality

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change the default post structure to `/resources/blog/%postname%/`

When I add this custom structure to permalinks in Wordpress it works for the url structure of the post, but I noticed Wordpress will no longer query for the page name after this change.

For example:

Previously wordpress could find `domain.com/name-of-product` even though the url structure was `domain.com/products/name-of-product`

It seems to work correctly as long as I'm only using the `%tags%`

Is there a better way of adding the url structure to the default blog post without breaking the page query functionality?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

mySQL queries use the % within the search/lookup section i.e.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE field1 LIKE '%fred%'"
```

Secondly: browsers use the % for special encoding of characters that are in the address bar (see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Percent-encoding_reserved_characters).